# NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, http, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying for an HTTP call on https. Here is my code snippet.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL
                                             URLWithString:@"https://testservice.fiamm.com/token"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSString *postString = @"username=TestIphone&Password=T3st1ph$n&Grant_type=password";

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Fetch the JSON response
NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

// Make synchronous request
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

// Construct a String around the Data from the response
NSString *strFiamm = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When I try in hurl or postman I get response proper but when I try in my code I get this error.

NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Any help or suggestions appreciated.!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed)

Answer (score 0):

The link that you mentioned here is not https certificate in it so use simple http not https

Edit #1

I tried these values

```
http://testservice.fiamm.com/token
username=TestIphone
Password=T3st1ph$n
Grant_type=password
```

and output is

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

that means your username password or key values are not correct

Comment: when I try only http then I get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't correctly setup the `Content-Length` header. The correct length of the content is the `postString` encoded in UTF-8 in bytes. `[postString length]` returns the number of UTF-16 code points (which is neither always the number of bytes in UTF-8 nor always the number of characters in the string).

You should also ensure that the post string is properly URL-encoded for use with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You'll find a number of posts regarding this on SO. The *definitive* guide, though, is this: [URL-encoded form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data). You should especially take note of the warning emphasised in the first paragraph about `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form data:

*"This form data set encoding is in many ways an aberrant monstrosity, the result of many years of implementation accidents and compromises leading to a set of requirements necessary for interoperability, but in no way representing good design practices. In particular, readers are cautioned to pay close attention to the twisted details involving repeated (and in some cases nested) conversions between character encodings and byte sequences."*

Having said this, I would strongly recommend to use another Content-Type to pass data to a server, for example JSON.

Answer (score 0):

add this methode in your class

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *) challenge {

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString: NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {

        NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL”];

        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host])
        {
            SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;

            NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];

            [challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        }
        else
        NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);

    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```