# Use NSURLSession call api on https server not worked on ios9, worked on ios8

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, https, ios9, app-transport-security

Use NSURLSession call api on https server not worked on ios9, worked on ios8

```
 NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/api"]];

    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                      completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                          if (error) {
                                                              NSLog(@"----: %@", error);
                                                          } else {
                                                              NSLog(@"-------: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                                          }
                                                      }];
```

When run on simulator or device, on device before iOS9, i'll get right response.
But when run on iOS9+, will get

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda12f29830 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.example.com/api, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

I have tried some methods

1. Disable ATS in plist file

   `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>`

   2. Add NSExceptionDomains
   3. use command `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://www.example.com` to test server connection, All configuration return FAIL

Any suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you try following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser

Comment: Thanks, Peer. I've tried this solution, but nothing happened. I'm checking server configurations.

Comment: I've resolved it. There are wrong configurations on server. Nginx configures ssl_protocol with TLSv.12 TLSv1.1 TLSv1, but openssl version 0.96 is not support TLSv1.2. upgrade openssl version 1.0.1 to enable this feature.