# iOS (Objective-C): An SSL error has occurred while fetching user info from LinkedIn API

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,location:(name),positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes))?format=json
```

I've added the following XML in the Info.plist file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It was working earlier. I am not sure why the LinkedIn web service now throws a SSL error?

Comment: CHECK THIS-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser

Comment: It is not working!! i have tried this!!

Comment: Have you enabled arbitary Loads in info.plist or checked that you are signing with authorized CA. Check for your certificate is still valid.??

Comment: Yeah, I have enabled arbitary loads. Sever is LinkedIn. How can i check CA and certificate valid?