# ICalendar subscription not working on ios

Tags: java, ios, web-services, tomcat, icalendar

I developed a Eclipse RAP application for an university. This application runs in a tomcat webserver. The application contains a java webservice for icalendar data. The users can subscribe to this webservice. In Outlook, Google Calendar and Calendar on Mac everything works fine. But if we try to connect from an ios device we are getting the following error in our tomcat access log:

[13/Oct/2017:13:53:56 +0200] "GET /"Link to our Application"/Calendar/$2a$06$lQltzFeH8AVlVeR8Ku/cal.ics HTTP/1.1" 406 1132

Additionally we are getting an error on our device that the connection with SSL ist not possible. Im confused because it works on mac.

I have to apologize for my spelling because english is not my first language.

Does anyone know how to fix this HTTP 406 error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS9 getting error “an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser)

Comment: my guess is that it has something to do with the App Transport Security, you need to disable it, the link in my first comment explains how to do that

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the end the error was that the webservice produced text/plain instead of text/calendar.