# HTTPS image not rendering in react native image

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I am trying to render an image "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc42.jpg" which works fine in a web browser, but in a react-native image the image does not appear.

I am attempting to do :

```
 <Image
style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }}
source={{
    uri:
        "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc42.jpg"
}}
/>;
```

This also does not work:

```
 <Image
style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: "cover" }}
source={{
    uri:
        "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc42.jpg"
}}
/>;
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: try removing the "https" before the `//` in your URL.

Comment: So do you mean like ://www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc42.jpg

or like www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc42.jpg ?

Comment: without the `:`

Comment: Both //www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc‌​42.jpg and www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc‌​42.jpg did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code, initially I did not get the image, then I handle the error using **onError** handler and found the following error

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

You may look into the stackoverflow answers for this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser/32854670)

I tried the first solution by changing

> info.plist

with following configuration and it worked

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Have a look into [this](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) document, above approach is ***not recommended***, instead they have suggested other way (it is also mentioned in the linked stackoverflow answer).

Hope this will help.

Comment: No error, the picture just does not appear. Were you able to get it to work with that configuration?

Comment: have u tried with `onError` handler callback and check the error on console?

Comment: Try like this `<Image onError={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.error) } style={{height: 200, width: 200}} source={{uri:'https://www.edamam.com/web-img/22c/22c27bdc6b8dc67215c7478cb4e5dc42.jpg'}}/>` to get the error. Also re-build ur app after changing info.plist.

Comment: I got An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Comment: Yes, the same error that I got, then I changed the info.plist and re-start the npm server with cache reset, then re deploy the app and it worked. Did u redeployed the apo?

Comment: I did a clean in xcode and then a build + deployed, but i can try again with resetting the simulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159200/discussion-between-prasun-pal-and-jkurs).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who thinks this is not a HTTPS issue, also check that your image is not a webp image.

Even if the title of the image says it's a .png or .jpg, try to save the image. If it says Google's WebP then you'll need to convert the image into a React Native friendly image file type.

Hope this helps!