# Use an API without ssl in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ssl, afnetworking

**Here is my code**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *opManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

opManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[opManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];

opManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = NO;
opManager.securityPolicy.validatesCertificateChain = NO;

NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"phone_number":self.phoneNumberTextField.text,
                             @"password":self.passwordTextField.text};

[opManager POST:@"http://www.example.com:8080/api.php/login"
     parameters:parameters
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Login Response Object %@",responseObject);
}
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Login2222-2 - %@",error);
}];
```

**Here is my error**

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
> and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9836,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x28185ce40 {Error
> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
> and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
> UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.example.com:8080/api.php/login,
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
> anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9836,
> _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
> connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.example.com:8080/api.php/login,
> _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9836}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.example.com:8080/api.php/login,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.example.com:8080/api.php/login,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

Normal for the first time login.For the second time, these error is indicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS9 getting error “an SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov was the same as tested