# iOS9 PayPal SDK - "An SSL error has occurred...."

Tags: ios, ssl, paypal

I'm getting the same error as reported in this question [iOS9 getting error “an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser)

I've checked with SSL labs using the PayPal URL https://mobileclient.paypal.com and it tells me that the it only supports the following ciphers...

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

Which don't match exactly the ciphers listed in the Apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

I wanted to ask is it the fact the ciphers aren't exactly the same the issue? I certainly don't want to bypass ATS as far as PayPal is concerned, do I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the documentation further which is what I should of done before asking the question! But to allow the ciphers that are listed I need to turn off `NSExceptionRequireForwardSecrecy` for that URL, from the docs...

`NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` A Boolean value for overriding the requirement that the domain support forward secrecy using ciphers.

`YES` is the default value and limits the ciphers to those shown in Default Behavior.

Setting the value to `NO` adds the following the list of accepted ciphers:

- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Answer (score 0):

As [Flexicoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285190/flexicoder) wrote you have to disable `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`. 
Add this to your **Info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourDomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```