# Swift 2 ios 9 complaining about http even though I am using https to connect to amazon s3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to load images from **amazon s3** (async).

But I get these errors in my log:

**NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL,-9802)**

I am making all my api calls with "https", it worked in ios 8.3 / xcode6

So

Comment: Seems like you are having same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: You should take a look at a [post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2QM69ZE6BGTYX/Preparing-Your-Apps-for-iOS-9) on AWS Mobile Development Blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into the HTTPS errors of App Transport Security read here:
[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/32701693#32701693)

But the basic jist is add the following to your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

You can do that via a text editor or in XCODE as such:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked! But is that enough? Looking at: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2QM69ZE6BGTYX/Preparing-Your-Apps-for-iOS-9
they suggest to add some more stuff

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your info.plist exactly as typed.

NSAppTransportSecurity

Once you create that make its value a dictionary called

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

Set the value to true or yes

Comment: Thanks it worked! But is that enough? Looking at: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2QM69ZE6BGTYX/Preparing-Your-Apps-for-iOS-9 they suggest to add some more stuff

Answer (score 2):

You are running into the HTTPS errors of App Transport Security read here:
[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/32701693#32701693)

But the basic jist is add the following to your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But is that enough? Looking at: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2QM69ZE6BGTYX/Preparing-Your-Apps-for-iOS-9 they suggest to add some more stuff