# phonegap app throws error related to ios 9 TLS 1.2 enforcement

Tags: cordova, ssl, ios9, tls1.2

is there phonegap option to allow all the untrusted ssl connections in your app. Apple introduced new enforcement in ios 9 where it only supports ssl connections where servers support TLS 1.2. Several forums posts are suggesting to edit info.plist to add option which is probably not supported by phonegap. What is possible solution for phonegap app to load urls which does not support TLS 1.2? Here is one of the post that suggestion solution for native app [kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802 when connecting to a server by IP address through HTTPS in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through)

Comment: you can use this plugin until official support is added https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-transport-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now I don't believe there is "official" support by Cordova/PhoneGap for this setting. It's ok to edit your project's plist, if necessary. Like everyone else is suggesting, you're going to have to edit your app's info.plist file if you want to get around this issue today. Add the contents of this [patch](https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa), and you'll be good to go.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.