# Async background requests

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, nsurl

I have a problem with this error:

```
CMDPusher[28340:7617667] [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9802]
CMDPusher[28340:7616111] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

It appears when I try to call Http2 request to apns async:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
   pusher.send(token: token, topic : "bundleid", priority : 10, payload :payload as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, completed: nil)
}
```

When I try to call it synchronously (without DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async). It's ok.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802 when connecting to a server by IP address through HTTPS in iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through)