# "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, ios11

I have update my iOS device to iOS 11 from then I'm getting

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0449f00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/register, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/register, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

My server is SSL only with AWS SHA-256 Certificate. How can I resolve it.
I'm using AFNetworking (3.1.0)

Comment: Check your App Transport Security setup - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through for possible avenues of investigation

Comment: If you have SSL pinning enabled with AFNetworking, then make sure that you have the googleapis certificate in your bundle.