# WKWebView fails to load static files when served via PerfectHTTPServer

Tags: swift, perfect

I'm trying to load WKWebView by running a local server (PerfectHTTPServer), and serving files from the documents folder in the iPhone application. The path is correct since this works with a server launched with Swifter. This is code snippet I use to launch the server 
    try HTTPServer.launch(name: "localhost", port: 9009, documentRoot: serverPath)

The error that is returned in console is: 
    [INFO] Starting HTTP server localhost on :::9009 
2018-05-01 15:03:54.929275+0530 WebViewTest[18991:1997516] [BoringSSL] Function nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished: line 1386 Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLFatalAlert(-9802) alert 
2018-05-01 15:03:54.934444+0530 WebViewTest[18991:1997516] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x103090350]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802) 
2018-05-01 15:03:54.935133+0530 WebViewTest[18991:1997516] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

I did some research and found that Apple recommends to use NSAllowsLocalNetworking, to get around similar problem. However, this still doesn't help in my case. I've also tried to introduce 'Exception Domains' and provide localhost, which works for Swifter, but not for Perfect.

Has anybody else faced a similar issue, or, can provide any pointers?

My environment is 
XCode: 9.2 (9C40b), 
iOS: 11.2.5, 
PerfectHTTPServer: 3.0.15 (Tag), 
Swift: 3.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it hard to tell with no code example, but it looks like problem with SSL settings,
it can be a problem with your settings, 
for example you try call 
**https://** instead of **http://** on client.

also try to look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through) to get help with error `kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802`