# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9860)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, handshake, boringssl

I am getting the error: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9860)

The same code is working fine in IPhone 8 with os version 11.3.1 but in IPhone 6 with os version 12.2 it is not able to fetch the response.

I am already having below in plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Complete log:

> 2019-06-03 10:55:07.459917+0530 MyApp[12858:2218159] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished(1543) [C16.1:2][0x102f28c30] Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLClosedNoNotify(-9816) alert
>   2019-06-03 10:55:07.461886+0530 MyApp[12858:2218159] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished(1543) [C15.1:2][0x102f9a330] Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLClosedNoNotify(-9816) alert
>   2019-06-03 10:55:07.463252+0530 MyApp[12858:2218159] TIC TCP Conn Failed [16:0x28048db00]: 3:-9816 Err(-9816)
>   2019-06-03 10:55:07.466969+0530 MyApp[12858:2218159] TIC TCP Conn Failed [15:0x28048e280]: 3:-9816 Err(-9816)
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.087508+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C17.1:2][0x102d7d020] Alert level: fatal, description: inappropriate fallback
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.088580+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C17.1:2][0x102d7d020] [boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.089000+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205) [C17.1:2][0x102d7d020] 4345208920:error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.250.2/ssl/tls_record.cc:586:SSL alert number 86
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.089466+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3617) [C17.1:2][0x102d7d020] SSL_AD_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.090298+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C18.1:2][0x102fed0f0] Alert level: fatal, description: inappropriate fallback
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.090387+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C18.1:2][0x102fed0f0] [boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.090448+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205) [C18.1:2][0x102fed0f0] 4345208920:error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.250.2/ssl/tls_record.cc:586:SSL alert number 86
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.090479+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3617) [C18.1:2][0x102fed0f0] SSL_AD_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.093938+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] TIC TCP Conn Failed [17:0x280497000]: 3:-9860 Err(-9860)
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.095442+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9860)
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.095507+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] Task <06FCD0BC-4B03-45CC-B67D-02578B332F5A>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9860])
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.096102+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] TIC TCP Conn Failed [18:0x280495bc0]: 3:-9860 Err(-9860)
>   2019-06-03 10:55:08.097280+0530 MyApp[12858:2218068] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9860)

TCP connection failure is something to do with handshake failure, but I can not get the reason of handshake failure..

code :

```
    +(void) fetchAndStoreAppConfig :(NSDictionary *)configuration mudulesToUpdate:(NSArray *)listItems withUser:(NSString *)email trigger:(NSString *)trigger {
    dispatch_queue_t SDKDataFetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SDKData Fetch Queue",NULL);
        dispatch_async(SDKDataFetchQueue, ^{

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [APICommunication getRequest:configuration mudulesToUpdate:listItems withUser:email trigger:trigger];
            NSDictionary *jsonValues = [SdkUtil getResponseFromApi:request];
            NSLog(@"API response %@",jsonValues);
            });
    }

    +(NSMutableURLRequest * _Nullable) getRequest :(NSDictionary * _Nullable)config mudulesToUpdate:(NSArray * _Nullable)listItems withUser:(NSString * _Nullable)email trigger:(NSString * _Nullable)trigger{
        NSError *err;
        NSData *convertedData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:listItems options:0 error:&err];
        NSString* entitiesStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:convertedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *entitiesStrtoURL = [entitiesStr stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

        NSString *completeURLStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:[self getBaseFormate],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",config[CONFIG_BASE_URL]],@"v4/sdk?",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",config[CONFIG_APP_ID]],entitiesStrtoURL, email, trigger];
        NSLog(@"SDK API: %@",completeURLStr);
        return [self getGetRequest:config url:completeURLStr];
    }

+(NSMutableURLRequest*)getGetRequest:(NSDictionary *)config url:(NSString *)completeURLStr{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:completeURLStr];
    NSString *authStr = [self getAuthString:config];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:authStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];
    return request;
}

    +(NSDictionary *)getResponseFromApi:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request{
        __block BOOL done = NO;
        __block NSDictionary * jsonValues;
        NSLog(@"sdk getResponseFromApi: %@",request);
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[APICommunication getSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if(data){
                NSError *errShow;
                jsonValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&errShow];
                NSLog(@"sdk JSon Description jsonvalues :%@",jsonValues.description);
                if(errShow == nil){
                    NSLog(@"sdk Error: %@",error);
                    done = YES;
                }
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"sdk Error description :%@",error.debugDescription);
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ErrorResponse" object:nil userInfo:nil];
            }
        }];

        [dataTask resume];

        while (!done) {
            NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:date];
        }
        return jsonValues;
    }
```

Comment: Please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through

Comment: @VRAwesome not working.

Comment: Can you please put your code snippet?

Comment: which code part?

Comment: Bunch of Code Where you are making request.

Comment: updated my question, could you please have a look on it?