# dataTaskWithRequest returning empty responseObject on 200s (ios 8.3 builds on ios 9 only)

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession, ios9

This is not a duplicate of [NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed)

Things I know or confirmed:

- Using default nsurlsession configuration
- Callback reached with error == nil
- [response allResponseHeaders] looks healthy and status code 200
- Not an ATS ios 9.0 problem. Proper https, and http 200 status code
- Confirmed request/response is normal using curl
- ONLY happens on a ios 8.3 build, targeting 7.1, and running on a 9.0
  device (all devices running prior versions of ios are fine)

**Update**: 
This has now been fixed with ios9 Beta2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed with ios9 Beta2.

Comment: Just for clarity: You mean, then, that in the original question it should have said "9.0 beta 1 device"? :)