# Handling App Transport Security (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Tags: security, ssl, ios9, tls1.2

You run this code:

```
let URL = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/wave_earth_mosaic_3.jpg"
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: URL)!)
UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

and you get this:

> 2015-09-11 16:33:47.433 Cassini[21200:447896]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Digging a bit deeper shows SHA1 signature is used.

```
maximveksler$ openssl s_client -connect www.nasa.gov:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text -in /dev/stdin | grep "Signature Algorithm"
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

So as of Sep 11, 2015 NASA are using insecure connection, now what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Why did it happen?

Because using insecure web is bad for your users privacy.

Beginning with iOS9 Apple are enforcing secure connections your app makes to any resource accessed via HTTP. This means that the server you are connecting to needs to follow up to date secure connection best practices.

As of Sep, 2015 these include:

- Use [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) (and not plain http)
- Sign the certificate using [SHA-2](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)
- Use [Forward Secrecy](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/04/why-web-needs-perfect-forward-secrecy)

More info can be found at [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)

## What can you do?

Manage your own servers? Fix it! make sure they are strong and secure. You can verify that your server is good by testing it online with [shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com](http://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com) or locally with any of the methods outline [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_SSL/TLS_Ciphers,_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection_(OTG-CRYPST-001))

If you are connecting to [other servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194201/48062), there are options to "white list" problematic resources, this is discouraged.

### Decrease security of a specific URL

Go to your `Info.plist` and add the following entries:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.nasa.gov</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Your plist should look like this: 
[image]

### Globally turn off App Transport Security

Note, this is a really really bad idea.

Go to your `Info.plist` and add the following entries:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Your plist should look like this: 
[image]

Comment: Can you inform if App Transport Security enforces port 443? Or can I use any port I wish (for RESTful APIs)?

Comment: BTW, not only NASA but Amazon's AWS HTTPS file servers does not meet the App Transport Security requirements at the moment. So if your app relies on assets that are hosted on AWS servers, you'll see this error.

Comment: How did you know about the App Transport Security Tech note you posted? How do you stay ontop of Apple changes like this without waiting for your ios code to break?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil i check apple documentation, follow WWDC announcements and view the lecture videos. Read news and weekly emails and keep up to date on twitter. It's my responsibility as a professional.

Comment: @MaximVeksler Thanks. I'm jealous of the professionals that have the luxury of devoting that much time to one part of the stack.