# How to catch App Transport Security blocked requests

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, app-transport-security

I want to detect when a request has been blocked by ATS so I can log this error (on an external service like Crittercism for instance).

Does Apple provide any API for that ? I couldn't find anything online.

Thanks

Comment: [SO 31193579](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193579/how-can-i-figure-out-which-url-is-being-blocked-by-app-transport-security?rq=1) might help

Comment: Indeed, its useful to get more information but I was thinking about something more automatic and dynamic. Like the observer pattern, where a notification would be sent only when ATS blocks a request so a specified function could be executed. No idea if Apple has such API.. Thanks for the tip anyway ;)