# Firebase tries to load http, blocked by App Transport Security

Tags: google-analytics, firebase, ios8, ios9, firebase-analytics

Using Google Firebase in my ios swift app, I found the infamous message in my console output:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

Using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193579/how-can-i-figure-out-which-url-is-being-blocked-by-app-transport-security), I was able to find that this is triggered by a request to load `http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js`, which is presumably from Firebase Analytics.

Do I need to add an exception for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the `firebase/analytics` module (`firebase 7.1.0`) inside a react app using firebase hosting and I was getting an error trying to load the googletagmanager (which I am NOT doing explicitly, it is coming from the module).

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=someGTM-id'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I am not importing google analytics from inside the index.html file, rather I am loading firebase/analytics from a javascript file with basically:

```
 import firebase from 'firebase/app';
 import 'firebase/analytics';
 const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "api-key",
    authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseUrl: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-id",
    storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
    appId: "app-id",
    measurementId: "G-measurement-id",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

I found: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

And fixed it by placing the following line inside my `index.html` file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js is not used by Firebase.  Perhaps one of the other SDKs you are using accesses this script.

Answer (score 0):

You do if you wish to use Firebase Analytics. Alternatively, you can disable analytics in the Firebase plist file.