# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)

Tags: ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

So I have tried the fixes mentioned in the solutions that come up when I search for this issue but on Visual Studio I still get these issues for my iOS web view project. The android version works fine, but iOS does not load the web page properly.

Tried these fixes mainly:
[NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927368/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802)

I've added this to my Info.plist file:

```
     <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
      <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
            <key>site.co.za</key>
            <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
           <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
           <true/>
         </dict>
         </dict>
        </dict>
```

Our site isn't secure but is there any way that I can bypass this so that I can load the mobile site properly like it does on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add following Dict in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Our Domain is secure but this error happens. Also Would this affect App store release?? since the documentation says we need justification to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to TRUE.