# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801) in SWIFT 3 and Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, nsurlconnection

Hi please read the whole thing before down vote,

I have tried this solutions already, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776859/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9801) ,[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9/35949346), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791361/nsurlsession-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813-self-signing-cer) but still no solution,

Now my problem here is I am trying to connect app to Camera in same LAN, so URL : https://LocalIP:PORT/cam_username/cam_password, in response I should get Image, this is the code just incase for reference.

```
        let url = URL(string: url1)
        if url != nil
        {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async 
        {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            if (data != nil)
            {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {                    
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row : i, section : 0)
                if let cell : CamTableViewCell = self.tableView .cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CamTableViewCell
                {

                    cell.ImageLive.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }

            });
            }
            }
        }
```

Response : data = nil
and this message in console

**[] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9801]
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)**

EDIT : my plist contains this

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`

NOTE: URL works fine and shows me Image on Browser.

Comment: What do the relevant keys in your Info.plist look like?

Comment: As the URL is in the local network try `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` rather than `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`.

Comment: @vadian Still didn't help me shows same error message [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9801]
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)

Comment: why did it get down vote ? If so give me answer to this problem.