# In <= iOS 8 is OK. But iOS 9, i get error

Tags: ios, afhttprequestoperation, afhttpclient

**I get error:**

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x15d275b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}}}
```

**My code:**

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:info];
[request setTimeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    [self.delegate requestSuccess:[NSNumber numberWithInt:REQUEST_TYPE_LOGIN] result:[operation responseString]];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self.delegate requesFailed:[NSNumber numberWithInt:REQUEST_TYPE_LOGIN] result:[operation responseString]];
}
```

Any ideas for help me?

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 9 the default is to only allow https. You can opt out by adding keys to Info.plist : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Comment: Thanks Stefan so much.
But still get this error.

I also do by this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9

Any ideas?

Comment: No other ideas really, sorry. You seem to use an old AFNetworking that doesn't use NSURLSession etc. Have you tried upgrading to latest AFNetworking?

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Solved. I just upgrading to latest AFNetworking and it works. Thanks so much :)

Comment: which version of AFNEtworking you have upgrated? can you send me the link of it?