# iOS9 App Transport Security

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http, ios9

I am attempting to send a http:// request however, ATS keeps blocking my request. I have turned on `Allow Arbitrary Loads` in the `Info.plist` and it still gives me the same error:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

[image]

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634738/ios-9-nsurlconnection-deprecated/33044935#33044935

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add exceptions for specific domains in your Info.plist
```

You can bypass this by adding this key to your info.plist of the project

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary `App Transport Security Settings` should be named `NSAppTransportSecurity`. And there should be only one thing in there which is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` boolean. Something like this.

[image]