# Image Not uploading to server by POST in Objective C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, multipartform-data

I am using POST method and multipartMethod to upload image from iphone to server. My Objective-C code is

```
__weak AuthAPIClient *client = [AuthAPIClient sharedClient];
    [client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Saving data to server..."];
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    if ([self isInternetAvailable]) {
    NSString *userId =[[AppSettings sharedAppSettings] getUserName];
    NSString*replacedName=[userId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
        NSDictionary *parametersDic = @{@"user_name":userName,@"image_data":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uploads/%@.jpeg",replacedName]};

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parametersDic options:0 error:nil];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];


    /////////////////////////////Test code////////////////////////////////
    NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagedata, 1.0);///imagedata is an UIImage passing in parameter of method.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"update_profile.php" parameters:json constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",userId] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSLog(@"response request %@",request);
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

                    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

                }];
 [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         //             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
         NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(responseString);
         if (responseString != nil && ![responseString isEqualToString:@""] &&  operation.response.statusCode == 200) {
             NSError *error;
             // NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
             NSMutableArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
             NSLog(@"hello response %@",responseString);

         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"hello response failr %@",responseString);

             if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceHelperSavePersonalInfoDataWithDetailsFailed:error:)]) {
                 [self.delegate serviceHelperSavePersonalInfoDataWithDetailsFailed:self error:@"No Response Recieved."];
             }
         }

     }
                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Error");
                                         //                                             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                         NSMutableString *errorMsg = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                                         [errorMsg appendString:@"Error Occured"];

                                         if(operation.response == nil)
                                         {
                                             [errorMsg appendString:@"Service not available. Please try again"];

                                         }
                                         else if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {
                                             [errorMsg appendString:@"Service not available. Please try again"];
                                         }
                                         else if (operation.response.statusCode == 403) {
                                             [errorMsg appendString:@"Request forbidden. Please try again"];

                                         }
                                         else {
                                             NSData *jsonData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                                    error:nil];
                                             if (json != nil) {
                                                 [errorMsg appendString:[json objectForKey:@"message"]];
                                             }

                                         }

                                         [errorMsg appendString:@" service is not available."];

                                         if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceHelperSavePersonalInfoDataWithDetailsFailed:error:)]) {
                                             [self.delegate serviceHelperSavePersonalInfoDataWithDetailsFailed:self error:errorMsg];
                                         }

                                     }];
    [operation start];
}
else {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceHelperSavePersonalInfoDataWithDetailsFailed:error:)]) {
        [self.delegate serviceHelperSavePersonalInfoDataWithDetailsFailed:self error:@"Internet not available."];
    }
}
```

And my PHP file(update_profile.php) code is

```
<?php
require_once "DatabaseConnection.php";
 $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $txt = "not set";
 if(isset($_FILES)){

   $txt = serialize($_FILES); 
   $result = "hellll";
}

 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
 $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
     $file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
     $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
   // sendResponse(200, 'Upload Successful');
    //return true;
     }
```

I have used my same code in other project that working good but not working in this project.Does it matter with EL Capitan OSX? Because i have updated my OS. Anyone have any idea where i am wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Error is:
Data and image not recieved at server side.Nothing comes in isset($_FILES) and i have also check $_POST and $_REQUEST but server not recieving anything only "a:0{}" saving in 'newfile.txt'. i am creating file 'newfile.txt' at server but nothing comes in this file.

Comment: Not working means? Do you read some data in your server part? Does your iOS code falls into the failure case? What's the error? What does say the log console? Is Application Transport Security allowed?

Comment: please put the error u are getting

Comment: Data and image not recieved at server side. nothing comes in isset($_FILES). i am creating file 'newfile.txt' at server but nothing comes in this file.

Comment: please verify App Transport Security read my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634738/ios-9-nsurlconnection-deprecated/33044935#33044935

Comment: Yes App Transport security is allowed.

Comment: you are getting response in success block ?

Comment: Yes in success block but i have no idea why php script not accepting it.

Comment: Use AFNetworking.framework and upload image by using multipartFormRequestWithMethod. it will help you to upload image and its Easy

Comment: @JatinVashisht can you please elaborate? i am using afnetworking directly not by framework.

Comment: which version of AFnetworking you are using , use AFHTTPSessionManager for image uploading?

Comment: No i am not using AFHTTPSessionManager.

Answer (score 1):

//    For Objective-c code - converting uiimage to nsdata
//    ----
//    Note: in php side make coding for convert json string to image, easiliy find in google
//    ---

```
NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgProfileView.image,0.8);  //0.1 to 1.0 upto image resolution

NSString *encodedString1 =   [data1 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

NSMutableDictionary *dicImage=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dicImage setObject:encodedString1 forKey:@"image1"];
[dicImage setObject:[dic valueForKey:@"des1"] forKey:@"des1"]; // if added any extra filed then

NSMutableDictionary *dic_set_Sync=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic_set_Sync setObject:APPDELEGATE.strEmailId forKey:@"email"];
[dic_set_Sync setObject: dicImage forKey:@"compressor_sync"];


NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic_set_Sync options:0 error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: JSON encode error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.inspectab.com/app/webservice/offline/compressor_syc.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",
                    [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *paramsData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:paramsData];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: NSURLConnection error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

// examine the response

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"responseString: %@",responseString);

if(![responseString isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSDictionary *dicResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                                                options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"dicResponse: %@", dicResponse);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need modifications in my current code. i don't want to use other code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code for Image uploading i think it may help-

```
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]  multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@“youUrl” parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
} error:nil];


NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  // This is not called back on the main queue.
                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      //Update the progress view
                      //  [self.progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];

                      NSLog(@"Proggress%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
                  });




              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                      [HUD setHidden:YES];
                      UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please check Internet Connection!" message:@"Error" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                      UIAlertAction *ok=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
                      [alert addAction:ok];
                      [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                  } else {


                      // [HUD show:NO];
                      [HUD setHidden:yes];

                      NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);

                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: No i am not using AFHTTPSessionManager.