# Convertapi Failed SSL Handshake in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ssl, convertapi

I am trying to get an image using ConvertApi to get an image from a webpage URL. My problem is that iOS >9 requires SSL for connections, and even ConvertAPI gives us https URLs, the `SSL Handshake` keeps failing. Here's my code to get the image:

```
let stringData = "ApiKey=\(ConvertAPI.Key)&CUrl=\(anURL.absoluteString)";

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ConvertAPI.URL)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST" 
request.HTTPBody = stringData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in   
   let returnImage = UIImage(data: data!)
})
```

Please note that:

- If I **do** accept `http` (using info.plist method) and change the ConvertAPI URL to `http://` it works.
- If I **do not** accept `http` and set the `https://` in ConvertAPI URL it fails 3 times (3 logs about `failed ssl handshake` and then returns an error.
- Swift 2, Xcode 7.1

Is this a ConvertAPI SSL problem? Is this my code problem? or is this a Swift bug?

**EDIT**
This is the console log for error and object taken with a breakpoint:

```
2015-09-21 19:02:12.386 appname[14528:606252] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2015-09-21 19:02:12.387 appname[14528:606252] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
```

[image]

Comment: There are other exceptions you can make for ATS to accept ciphers with lesser security and so on.  You need to find out why the SSL handshake is failing - there should be a clue in the console.

Comment: We have no problems using ConvertApi with SSL, please post full SSL Handshake exception to better understand the problem.

Comment: Paulw11 & @Tomas thanks for the answer. I updated the question with more information. Please share the code (or solution) you are using SSL with iOS 9, if possible!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30748166/625521