# Swift/https: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed

Tags: ios, https, swift2, xcode7

Unfortunately this morning my XCode updated to version 7 and the iOS app I was developing with http now wants https. So, following many tutorials, I configured my MAMP server in order to use https/ssl creating a dummy certificate. Now in my iOS app URLs are like the following:

```
static var webServerLoginURL = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/loginM.php"
static var webServerGetUserTasks = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/handleTasks.php"
static var webServerGetUsers = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/handleUsers.php"
static var webServerGetProjects = "https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/handleProjects.php"
```

and they work fine if I try to access them in my browser.
I was used to access the database and php files with NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest() which now raises the error in title. For example, here's the line where error is raised:

```
if let responseJSON: [[String: String]] = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())) as? [[String: String]] {
...
}
```

and this is the complete error message:

```
2015-09-21 16:41:48.354 ExcogitoWeb[75200:476213] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-09-21 16:41:48.355 ExcogitoWeb[75200:476213] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection   HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I would like to know how to fix this. I've read some useful answers here but there are many things I still don't understand and if anyone would help/explain me I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this to your app's `Info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
    <dict>  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
    <true/>  
    </dict>
```

Comment: it's look so danger

Answer (score 3):

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

usually means that you're doing something not so good, and by looking at your `if`

```
if let responseJSON: [[String: String]] = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())) as? [[String: String]] {
```

I can see that there's a `data!`, but that data object is nil. You really should unwrap the optionals before using them, especially when working with remote data.

Then you have a network error, that's probably related to the `ATS` Apple added in iOS 9.

See another answer on how to *temporarily* disable ATS.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30748166/421755

edit: I see now that you added ssl to your localhost, that's good. However it's not enough for ATS to work, since it needs TLS 1.2 and not self-signed certificates.

Comment: Yes, I guess the problem is that data is nil because of that error network, I'll try to disable it as you said...all I have understood is that I should upgrade MAMP ssl/tls to 1.2...is it possible now? Or shall we wait?

Comment: I just edited the answer at the same time you commented. I think it's way easier to just disable `ATS` when using a local server. Make sure you enable it later on when you ship the app!

Comment: I've just read that TLS 1.2 will be available with OSX El Capitan...I really hope so. I'm developing this iOS app for an exam and I wouldn't like to look like a inexperienced guy to my teacher...thank you for your healp

Comment: sorry for the disturb..would you please tell me how to edit plist files? Because I don't see it with xml syntas...

Comment: sure, just right click on your plist-file in xcode, and select `Open As` `Source Code`. http://imgur.com/eq94tju

Comment: I thought I had made it work but now I get this: "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)"...

Comment: This is what I've added:

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>

Answer (score 1):

Really old question, but I thought I would respond. This usually happens when you try to unwrap an http object and it comes back nil.

Make sure that you unwrap your url and give it a default value.

example :

```
let jsonURL = "your https link to your json"
guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return } // dont force unwrap
```

hope this helps!