# Socket not connected in http domain base address

Tags: swift, sockets, socket.io

I am implementing a socket for a chat in my application. It will work fine for HTTPS domain and IP address base domain. But when I use the HTTP domain it is not able to connect and sometimes it said request time out. In android, it will be working fine.

I use pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift' library for ios.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33316033/560942

Comment: I already add this in .plist file

Comment: are you using namespaces like www.yourdomain.com/users/chat in the URL? I had an issue with namespace on  socket.IO-Client but the library has support for namespace if implemented correctly