# Image Bing API stopped working with Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ios9, xcode7, bing-api

In Xcode 6 this was working:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query='\(keywords2)'")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Client received real data with image information. But in Xcode 7 I receive from Bing an error:

> The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and
>   OAuth are supported

Any idea what is going on? As you see I use Basic authentication. With external HTTP client it works, get back real data.

Tried to set up `NSAppTransportSecurity` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9/30748166#30748166), but did not help

-

Tried to set `Info.plist`, but did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the following properties block inside of the main properties dictionary (under the first ).

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
<key>www.yourwebservicedomain.com</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.1</string>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</dict>
</dict>
Lazy Answer :-------------
```

https://www.facebook.com/1622413124641847/photos/a.1622657711284055.1073741827.1622413124641847/1655527087997117/?type=3