# iOS 9.1 Images and Videos not displaying in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7.1

I have develop one application in which there are so many photos and videos.
I have develop this app in xcode6.3 and it will work perfectly but now i have installed new xcode7.1 and when i'm trying to run this app in xcode7.1 it will run perfectly but i haven't seen any videos and images of my app.

Is that any chnage that i have to do in my code or is it any other problem

Comment: you are using api calls to load the data?

Comment: yes, i'm using API to load data. my videos and images are loaded from server.

Comment: then i suspect  the problem with http request you are using from ios9 apple discourages the use of HTTP request as part of the Apple Transport Security (ATS) are you using http or https ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Xcode7 Apple mandates that all url access should be HTTPS as a part of Apple Transport Security (ATS)

To overcome this you have to add the following item in your app info.plist file [image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting when calling your API?

Comment: There is no any error coming out. just videos and images are not displaying in app. other information from API is coming properly

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass this by adding this key to your info.plist of the project

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

for more details about ATS refer [NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9) 
http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: yes, i have added this but still not working. data loaded successfully only issue is coming with images and videos only.

Comment: in what format you are getting media files log the response you are getting and what are the values getting for the image key