# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “...” couldn’t be opened."

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurl

When I open a URL (like this `http://webserver/index.php/feeds/1.2/3.4/5/1000/`) in my app via Xcode I get a nil JSON string returned. It doesn't even seem to be talking to the server.

The exact same URL works when I paste it into a browser.

Reading up on similar problems, I tried restarting my Mac and iPhone but I get the same problem.

e.g. looking at the error object I see:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “1000” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http://webserver/index.php/feeds/1.2/3.4/5/1000/}
```

The webserver does not show any entries in the logs (it does if I paste the URL in the browser) when I'm running the app and go past that line of code.

==== UPDATE

I'm assuming it's something to do with this [NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9/30836686#30836686)

However, after adding the webservice domain to the plist (under NSExceptionDomains) I get a crash in CJSONDserializer in this method:

```
- (id)deserializeAsDictionary:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError;
{
if (inData == NULL || [inData length] == 0)
```

as follows:

```
Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x10)
```

and, after updating TouchJSON, I now have a crash here:

```
if (theData.length >= 4)
```

==== UPDATE 2

Interestingly, if I click the QuickLook icon in Xcode whilst on the breakpoint, it loads up the content just fine. And I can see a request at the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error is NSFileReadUnknownError.  That's not a file URL.  How, exactly, is your code trying to open this URL?

Comment: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a NULL pointer dereference.  Your theData object is getting deallocated in one thread while you're accessing it in another.  I can't tell you how or why that is happening, but that's what's happening there.