# Weird error code 4294966295 for NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, nsurlconnection

I am getting an unusual error when using `NSURLConnection`:

[image]

There are no logs, or nothing to go here. All I can get is the error code `4294966295`. Any idea what that might be?

I am running XCode7 and iOS9 on my device. I have already disabled ATS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

4294966295 is -1001 when seen as a signed 32 bit int.  This is `NSURLErrorTimedOut`.  You can look up the codes in `NSURLError.h`.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through lot of article,sites and links according to your question which says

> App Transport Security (ATS) enforces best practices in the secure
>   connections between an app and its back end. ATS prevents accidental
>   disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt; it
>   is also on by default in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11. You should adopt ATS
>   as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app
>   or updating an existing one.
>
> If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can
>   right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as
>   soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level
>   APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy.
>   If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement,
>   an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure
>   domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.

[image: In Plist, you need to set]

Please go through the below references

[NSURLDomainError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost)

[NSURLDomainErrorCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9)

[Transport Security](http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error)

[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error when trying to test from a device to the web server on my local machine thru port 81.  Worked fine in the simulator though. The firewall on my machine was blocking port 81 so turning the firewall off was the easy fix for me.