# SSLhandshake error in iphone device using cordova app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova

I am Using cordova@5.3.3 for building iphone application.
Our server is https and we have installed the server ssl certificate 
in iphone device.

During login page application we are getting error ( *captured from xcode logs while device plugged in*): -

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9847 ) NSURLSession NSRLConnection
>   HTTP Load failed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9847)

I checked with IOS Device: 8.3 and 9.2 and both of them having same issues.
in AppDelegate.m file we have made below changes but still it is not working.
(*although its not recommended but i just want to make it work first*)

```
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host {
    return YES;
}
```

i have updated app plist file by setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true under
NSAppTransportSecurity but still not working.

Our https server is TLS1.2 compliant.

I tried below settings also (step-3), but same issues.

[NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9)

How to debug/fix this problem. ?

Comment: No idea what's going wrong, but you can use a plugin for checking the cert: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin Works very well.