# xcode run a url without uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

How to run a URL in Xcode objective-c without using uiwebview

I try this code but its not work

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL]];
```

the url like this:

```
@"http://www...com/library/ws_setLike.php?book_ID=%@&user_ID=%@",bookID,userID];
```

Comment: What's the type of my URL? By "not work" what you mean? Is there any kind of error in `UIWebView` error delegate?

Comment: @NamshanNet if you do not want to use UIWebView what else are you planning on using, your code is for a webview

Comment: @Dom Bryan   its Post value (  ?book_ID=%@&user_ID=%@  )

Answer (score 0):

For non https urls you must allow arbitrary loads in NSAppTransportSecurity:
[NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9)

Comment: NSAppTransportSecurity is ok open

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do the trick: *(This is of course on the assumption that if you do not want to use a UIWebView you will want to use the default browser on the device)*

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www...com/library/ws_setLike.php?book_ID=%@&user_ID=%@",bookID,userID]];
```

Comment: Not this :( this'll open default browser on the device

Comment: Well then what are you planning on showing the webpage in? there is only UIWebView and the Browser on any iOS Device. Please be more clear