# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9814)

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-transport-security

I've been working on this project for a month and all internet requests were working fine until today, I am seeing this error whenever I execute a request :

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9814)
```

Although, in my info.plist, I added the APT configuration from the start:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Keep in mind, that everything was working fine, I didn't change anything.
I tried this, on iOS 9 and iOS 7, and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this in info.plist,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>YOURHOST.COM</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9) for more detail. hope this will help :)