# Cordova ios app can't load device data

Tags: ios, cordova

I searched a lot about my issue and I tried different solution, but it doesn't work :/

Link what I tried:
[NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9)

```
2016-06-24 10:51:56.760 <App Name>[1817:1004680] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

**UPDATE**

After adding the lines below:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
 </dict>
```

I get this error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

But when I follow the introduction of [developer apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) everything should be fine:

[nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bOoQ.png) result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add the following lines in `Classes/AppDelegate.m` above the `@implementation AppDelegate`:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host{
  return YES;
}
@end
```

What I'm using:

- cordova version 5.3.3
- platform: iio 4.2.0

helpful link: [NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-nsurlconnection-cfurlconnection-http-load-failed/29381)

Comment: This does not works for me - Cordova v7, ios 4.5, xcode 9, iOS 11.

Comment: This does not work for me either - Cordova v6, ios 4.5, xcode 10, iOS 12