# Alamofire 405 status code error

Tags: swift, api, laravel, alamofire, postman

I have a very simple POST API in this URL: https://lookaguide.com/api/test

The api are in Laravel 5.2 and this api only return a string that says: "All is OK"

This is the code of the API:

```
Route::post('test', function(){
    return response()->json(['All is OK']);
  });
```

When I use this API with Postman the api return the correct information. 
[image]

I'm using Alamofire 3.4, when I consume the API the 405 error appers as if the POST resquest did not exist.

This is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://lookaguide.com/api/test", parameters: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response

                }
        }
```

Error in Xcode when print respose.response

```
    Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7914a870> { URL: https://lookaguide.com/api/test } { 
status code: 405, headers {
        "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, private";
        Connection = "Keep-Alive";
        "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        Date = "Wed, 03 Aug 2016 18:24:49 GMT";
        "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=3, max=30";
        Server = "Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9";
        "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
        "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.22";
        allow = POST;
    } })
```

Any suggest?

Comment: Ok, I change that, but this don't fixe the error

Comment: did u add NSAppTransportSecurity to info.plist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9

Comment: I just added your code to a demo project and it ran without any problem. status: 200

Comment: Wich xcode version do you have?

Comment: xcode has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Where you added my code, and why you can ran the project but I can't?