# I want to find out a way to locate the exact failed request.(CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806))

Tags: swift, xcode, ssl, cfnetwork

I got an error log in my console `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)` by xCode.

How can I figure out which request is responsible for the failed log.

There are many requests both third party and my own server request when my app launched. I can not figure out which one having error.

Log console only gives me `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)`

ps: I'm using swift 3.0, Xcode 8. AFNetworking 3.0(seems request by AFNetworking don't have error, cause I use AFNetworking logger to log all request by AFNetworking )

when testing, iOS 8 and iOS 9 seems like make more failed logs than iOS 10.

ps: I have add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to my plist file, And many of my https and http requests have load successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9

Comment: @Alladinian I have updated my question

Comment: I want to find out a way to locate the exact failed request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 0)
```

will help log more details

reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1887/_index.html)

Burp Suite also gives some help, seems easier than wireshark. [reference](https://www.engadget.com/2011/02/21/how-to-inspect-ioss-http-traffic-without-spending-a-dime/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added following in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
```

If not added, then please add this, so that you will not get this error.

Comment: see my Updated question, I have add that