# Html Data to JSON to String Using Swift 4

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to decode html data to simple string but I get all html syntax along with 
I am using alamofire get method
Link for html data 
http://laorotava.municipiointeligente.es/webservices/getNewsAndroid.php?type=audioguides1_es

Any help will be appreciated

I have tried all codes and extension on stack overflow but unable to get proper results

```
 let urlString = "http://laorotava.municipiointeligente.es/webservices/getNewsAndroid.php?type=audioguides1_es"
        Alamofire.request(urlString).response { response in
            if let data = response.data{
                let str = data.html2AttributedString
                print(str)
            }
        }
```

I get String in along with html syntax

I want this text

> Te damos la bienvenida a La Orotava, el pueblo con mayor desnivel de
>   España.  Abarca desde las playas del Rincón, a nivel del mar, hasta
>   los 3718 metros del pico Teide, el punto más alto de España, cuya
>   última erupción fue en 1798. Se cree que el nombre Orotava deriva de
>   la palabra Arautápala, con el que denominaban a este territorio los
>   antiguos aborígenes guanches. Tras la conquista, fue declarada Villa
>   por el rey Felipe IV en 1648. Te invitamos a recorrerlo a través de
>   dos rutas diferentes: La Orotava Secreta o Ruta Azul y La Orotava
>   Legendaria o Ruta Verde.Cada ruta dura aproximadamente una hora y
>   media a paso normal y sus contenidos son diferentes. Si dispones de
>   tiempo, te recomendamos que hagas las dos rutas por separado para
>   disfrutar de rincones, leyendas y secretos que La Orotava te ofrece. A
>   lo largo del recorrido encontrarás, incrustadas en el suelo, placas
>   circulares de metal dorado. Cada placa indica el número de pista en el
>   color de la ruta a la que pertenece. Cuando te encuentres frente a
>   estas placas, pulsa el número de pista correspondiente.  Si no
>   dispones del tiempo suficiente, te recomendamos que elijas sólo una
>   ruta.  Pregunta al personal de la Oficina Municipal de Turismo, te
>   atenderán encantados y te ayudarán a elegir una de ellas en función de
>   tus intereses. También tienes a tu disposición folletos y otros
>   materiales en la oficina para ayudarte en esta decisión.  Ten en
>   cuenta que La Orotava está llena de calles pendientes con subidas y
>   bajadas muy pronunciadas. Si eliges la ruta de La Orotava Legendaria,
>   o Ruta Verde, te encontrarás un recorrido con menos desnivel.  Por
>   otro lado, la Ruta de La Orotava Secreta o Ruta Azul ofrece a los más
>   aventureros vistas panorámicas únicas desde las mayores alturas a las
>   que llega la visita. Te recomendamos realizar las rutas en horario de
>   oficina para que tengas la oportunidad de encontrar abiertos el mayor
>   número de espacios posible. Las iglesias suelen estar abiertas en
>   horario de culto.  Recuerda que tienes a tu disposición un botón de
>   pausa y otro de repetición de los últimos 10 segundos en el
>   reproductor, para hacerte más cómodo el recorrido.  Cualquiera de las
>   dos rutas está llena de sorpresas y rincones maravillosos. Adelante,
>   pulsa la ruta de tu elección y adentrémonos juntos en este paseo por
>   La Orotava.

Comment: exactly  what you want please update your question with an example

Comment: ok i will update

Comment: i tried that does not help

Comment: i might be doing wrong method please help me

Comment: the above link will do the same for you , you will get output like you want

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I think its very close still has some issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your answer is here**

```
extension String{

    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }

    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

**API Call**

```
let urlString = "http://laorotava.municipiointeligente.es/webservices/getNewsAndroid.php?type=audioguides1_es"

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

                do {

                    if let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (response.data as Data?)!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]{

                        if let body = jsonDict["body"] as? String{
                            print(body.htmlToString) // Your output is Here
                        }
                    }

                } catch _ {
                    print("Exception!")
                }
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your effort but giving crash in my end I am  still figuring out

``` NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 ```

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506939/10150796 Because recently I write this code in my project and share it it's working fine you can also see the output here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196512/discussion-between-nikunj-kumbhani-and-meet-ios-developer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create NSAttributedString from HTML string.

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to use HTML text:

textView.attributedText = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString

Comment: doest not effect i tried

Comment: past your HTML string here

Comment: i have done  Nikunj Kumbhani helped me

Comment: good, Due to NSAppTransportSecurity?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below Extension for Data & String

```
extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}

extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Implementation in your code should be Like this.

```
 let urlString = "http://laorotava.municipiointeligente.es/webservices/getNewsAndroid.php?type=audioguides1_es"
        Alamofire.request(urlString).response { response in
            if let data = response.data{
                let str:NSAttributedString = data.html2AttributedString //call the extension method here
                print(str)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried it but it again  printed  with html syntax and gives crash white assigning data to text view

Comment: try this let str:NSAttributedString = data.html2AttributedString

Comment: doesnt even help same  with html syntax